# Gravity Form Shortcode Confirmation

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Hi I am echoing a shortcode of a gform but I need to check what the confirmation message is programmatically in php to call a function if successful and another if failed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation message to be used is stashed in the `GFFormDisplay::$submission` property when the submission is processed so it can be retrieved when the form shortcode or block is processed on page render. You can access it like so:

```
$confirmation = rgars( GFFormDisplay::$submission, $form_id . '/confirmation_message' );
```

Alternatively you could use the [gform_confirmation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation/) filter to override the confirmation to be used when the submission is being processed, before it is added to the `GFFormDisplay::$submission` property e.g.

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation', function ( $confirmation, $form, $entry ) {
    if ( empty( $entry ) || rgar( $entry, 'status' ) === 'spam' ) {
        // Return the default confirmation for spam.
        return $confirmation;
    }

    // Check your condition here and replace the $confirmation if needed.
 
    return $confirmation;
}, 11, 3 );
```